# javascript setInterval animation loop not looping

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I know there are many variants of this, but I can't figure out why this one isn't looping. It runs through segmentConstruction only once.

```
        var timer;           
        timer = setInterval(segmentConstruction(multipointCoords,whaleTime), 1000);

        function segmentConstruction(multipointCoords,whaleTime){

            console.log(multipointCoords[0][0]);
            console.log(whaleTime[0][0]);
            console.log(i);

            if (i > 10) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
            else {
                i++;
                timer;
            };
        };
```

Comment: setInterval expects a function as a parameter, you are passing the result of calling a function

Comment: what is the variables i ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't pass a function argument this way.

You can call your **function with arguments** within an anonymous function.
This solution will work for all browsers:

```
timer = setInterval(function() {
    segmentConstruction(multipointCoords,whaleTime);
}, 1000);

function segmentConstruction(coords, time)
{
    // ...
}
```

This approach is only used for functions **without arguments**:

```
timer = setInterval(segmentConstruction, 1000);

function segmentConstruction()
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `setInterval(segmentConstruction(multipointCoords,whaleTime), 1000);` is identical to:

```
var t = segmentConstruction(multipointCoords,whaleTime);
setInterval(t, 1000);
```

Starting with IE10, you could:

```
setInterval(segmentConstruction, 1000, multipointCoords, whaleTime);
```

Comment: so what is the solution

Comment: @ArunPJohny - that is :-)

Comment: `starting with IE10` **and in other browsers since the dawn of time**

Comment: have to be careful @Amit .. MS Edge leads the way in some standards these days :p

Answer (score 0):

This is because segmentConstruction function call one time when you initiate interval.
There are 2 ways to fix it:

1. Wrap segmentConstruction into closure in setInterval construction like this:

   setInterval(function () {segmentConstruction(multipointCoords,whaleTime); }, 1000);
2. segmentConstruction should return closure:

   ```
   function segmentConstruction(multipointCoords,whaleTime){
       return function () {
           console.log(multipointCoords[0][0]);
           console.log(whaleTime[0][0]);
           console.log(i);

           if (i > 10) {
               clearInterval(timer);
           }
           else {
               i++;
               timer;
           }
       };
   }
   ```

Comment: Only 2? looks at other answers, there are a few more. There are others not listed as well.